# How to send a next thread once if the first thread was completely done in Jmeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a thread group with 50 users, here I want to see the load time for all the 50 concurrent users, I don't want to hit a server with parallel thread, i want to run it sequentially like I have to send a second thread once if the first thread is completely done

how can I do this in Jmeter, please help me with your answers

Answer (score 0):

Your statements are mutually exclusive:

- want to see the load time for all the 50 concurrent users
- I don't want to hit a server with parallel thread

So the options are in:

1. Change [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings to 1 user and 50 loops
2. Put your request(s) under [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) which ensures that its child(ren) is(are) run by only one thread at a time
3. Use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm) so the next user will start only when the previous user finishes